# c++ queue container

Tags: c++, queue

I have a problem with queues in my program. Having one queue I would like to use this queue, only with another id. Here is what I have now:

```
queue<R> queue;
queue<R> queue2;
...
while (! queue2.empty() )
{
  R r = queue2.front();
  queue2.pop();
  queue.push(r);
}
```

But it is linear. I hope that it is possible to do it in O(1) time. I tried to use references but I failed.

Comment: What do you mean in O(1) time? To put all elements from q2 to q1? Or something else?

Comment: What did you try that failed?

Comment: Why even change the name at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937621/why-does-std-queue-not-define-a-swap-method-specialisation - otherwise I would have said queue.swap(queue2);

Comment: I tried this way: `queue = queue2` and `queue = &queue2`. But it was not good. I would like to avoid copying all elements, because it takes long time in my program

Comment: Can you use C++11 or not?  Consider just using std::list, which would let you do list1.swap(list2)--you can still use it like a queue.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It's unlikely that simply changing containers off-the-cuff is the right thing to do.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: And even if it was, `std::list` is the worst container. Use a `std::deque` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us how you "failed", but references are [really easy](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources):

```
std::queue<R> queue;
std::queue<R>& queue2 = queue;
```

Job done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free `std::swap` function:

```
std::queue<R> queue2;
std::swap(queue1, queue2);
```

This just calls `swap` on the underlying container, so it should be fairly efficient.

(According to John Zwinck's [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937621/why-does-std-queue-not-define-a-swap-method-specialisation), this is a new feature of C++11, though, so older compilers may reject this or have an inefficient implementation.)